# Arch Linux on Raspberry Pi can't connect to WLAN netctl

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux, raspberry-pi

I can't connect to a WiFi network. I tried various methods (wpa_supplicant, wicd ...). At the moment I'm trying `netctl`.

When I enter the command: `systemctl --type=service` I see the following errors:

[image]

**netctl start wireless-home**

```
Job for netctl@wireless\x2dhome.service failed. See 'systemctl status
netctl@wireless\x2dhome.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

This is my netctl config file:

```
Description='A simple WPA encrypted wireless connection'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa
IP=dhcp
ESSID='Pruthenia 3.OG'
Key='XXXXXXXXXX'
```

**systemctl status netctl@wireless\x2dhome.service**

```
netctl@wirelessx2dhome.service - Networking for netctl profile wirelessx2dhome 
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service; static) 
Active: inactive (dead) Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)
```

**journalctl -xn output -->**

```
Dec 12 08:01:01 webcampi CROND[2765]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
Dec 12 09:01:01 webcampi crond[3490]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 12 09:01:01 webcampi CROND[3491]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 12 09:01:01 webcampi CROND[3490]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
Dec 12 10:01:01 webcampi crond[4216]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 12 10:01:01 webcampi CROND[4217]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 12 10:01:01 webcampi CROND[4216]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
Dec 12 11:01:01 webcampi crond[4941]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 12 11:01:01 webcampi CROND[4942]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 12 11:01:01 webcampi CROND[4941]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: whats the output of 'cat /etc/netctl/*wi*'? have you read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl#Basic_method so far?

Comment: Description='A simple WPA encrypted wireless connection'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa

IP=dhcp

ESSID='Pruthenia 3.OG'
# Prepend hexadecimal keys with \"
# If your key starts with ", write it as '""<key>"'
# See also: the section on special quoting rules in netctl.profile(5)
Key='XXXXXXXXXX'
# Uncomment this if your ssid is hidden

Comment: and yes i did, that was the guide i was following

Comment: then whats the output of 'systemctl status netctl@wireless\x2dhome.service'? please edit your question again

Comment: netctl@wirelessx2dhome.service - Networking for netctl profile wirelessx2dhome
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service; static)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)

Comment: 'journalctl -xn'? just post everything you try

Comment: I have often found the output of journalctl  singularly uninformative. You should go to /usr/lib/systemd/system, search for the service you are trying to start (netctl, in this case), take a look at netctl.service, see which file is the relevant binary, (/usr/bin/netctl restore in this case) and run it directly from the CLI. Please then post the output.

Comment: could you explain the procedere a little bit more newbie friendly to me thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have a problem with the name of your essid, try avoiding special characters like the space and the dot.

something happened while creating your netctl profile which is causing `\x2d` in its name.

Comment: I dont think thats the problem, i can connect on another raspberry with debian on the same ssid. Also as you can see in the picture i postet there is a problem with the services itself